# How Do I Find Whether An Item Is Within A Set Or Not?

Tags: python

I have been having this annoying problem where I have an int, and I want to see if that int has an equivalence in a set. If it does, I don't want it in my "nset" values. However, when I attempt this, which seems pretty straightforward, it acts like the item has not been filtered properly.

Example Logs:

```
RDM is 8
RDM is not in
{1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
{1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8}
{2, 5, 6, 7, 8}
```

Code:

```
    nset = list(range(1, self.n2 + 1))

    for i in nset:
        if(i in self.valuesInRows[space[0]]):
            nset.remove(i)
        elif(i in self.valuesInCols[space[1]]):
            nset.remove(i)   
        elif(i in self.valuesInBoxes[self.spaceToBox(space[0], space[1])]):
            nset.remove(i)

    rdm = -1

    while(rdm not in nset):
        rdm = random.randint(0, self.n2)
        print("RDM {}".format(rdm))

    print("RDM is {}".format(rdm))
    print("RDM is not in")
    print(self.valuesInBoxes[self.spaceToBox(space[0], space[1])])
    print(self.valuesInRows[space[0]])
    print(self.valuesInCols[space[1]])
    print()

    return rdm
```

Any explanation would be fantastic, because I've looked at the documentation and it shows that this is the approach I would want to do, but I seem to be missing something.

Comment: You're removing from a list while you iterate over it.

Comment: BTW, in Python, [the style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is to name variables `like_this`, not `likeThis`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using list instead of sets. Lists are standard Python data types that store values in a sequence. Sets are another standard Python data type that also stores values. The major difference is that sets, unlike lists or tuples, cannot have multiple occurrences of the same element and store unordered values.

By definition, sets won't allow for duplicate values. In lists, Before inserting the value, you have to check the occurrence by `in` keyword.

1. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations

Comment: There are no set insertion operations in the posted code, and you don't have to do an `in` test before set insertion - inserting an already-present element will just do nothing.

Comment: @user2357112: They didn't say you need to do so for `set`s, just that `in` testing would be needed to avoid duplicates in `list`s.

Comment: @user2357112 Set is mentioned in the Question title.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Looks like I misread that, but there are no list insertion operations in the posted code either.

Comment: @Thuvarakan: Sets are involved, but no insertion operations.

Comment: I am saying that the membership check is not necessary for sets.